# How can I print source code on OS X with line numbers, line-wrapping, margins, formatting?

Tags: macos, mac, printing, text-editors

I'm looking through some of Wordpress' core code and would like to print it out to review.

I'm looking for a tool that

- defaults to a monospace font
- can wrap long lines
- possibly print line numbers in the left column
- maximize space usage on a page (i.e. would be nice if it didn't start with 2" margins)

What I've tried already:

- Textmate: Unable to change screen and print font size independently. I don't want to have to switch back and forth
- TextEdit: Options don't seem very helpful
- MS Word: Have to paste the input, change line spacing and font. Painful.
- Coda: Has the most options. Closest to what I want so far. Does not seem to save my print preferences as defaults though.

Comment: Syntax highlighting (i.e. color) if a known programming language?

Comment: You might want to try to use the compiler that you usually use. Visual studio does a good job, I imagine your compiler (one of them maybe) might do the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [`enscript --line-numbers -f fontname --word-wrap --margins=…  filename`](http://www.manpages.info/macosx/enscript.1.html)

On my Linux systems `enscript filename`, by default, prints the file to my default printer (which understands Postscript - I don't buy any other sort).

In OS X, you can print to a PDF file using `pstopdf`:

```
enscript --line-numbers -p - --word-wrap Session.java | pstopdf -i -o ~/out.pdf
```

You can tweak global or personal settings for enscript to make those options standard so you just enter a command `enscript filename`. You may be able to set up an option in your favourite text editor that invokes external command enscript for you.

Comment: See here for an [OS X workflow with enscript](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/2223). Hope you don't mind the edit.

Comment: The above links no longer work, but here's on that does http://qosys.info/642/printing-source-code-mac-os

Comment: well it does not syntax highlights...

Comment: @ethanjyx. [It should do](http://blog.vinceliu.com/2008/06/printing-syntax-highlighted-source-code.html), see `enscript --help-highlight | less` and then use something like `enscript --color=1 -Eruby ... sourcefile.rb`

Comment: Enscript isn't bundled in MacOS 10.14, but it was an easy install with Homebrew.